# Amount result in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, max

When I try this query

```
Select S.Name,S.No,
SUM(Case when s.Furit =’Mango’ then total else 0 end) as Mango,
SUM(Case when s.Furit =’Apple’ then total else 0 end) as Apple,
SUM(total) total, 
Sum(convert(int,Am)) Amount, MAX(S.Value) Value
 from (
Select
 Veh_table.Name, Veh_table.No, VV_table.Furit, count(VV_table.Furit) as total,  Veh_table. Amount as Am, Veh_table. Value
from VV_table 
inner join Veh_table on VV_table.MID=Veh_table.ID
inner join Re_table on Veh_table.RID=Re_table.RID
WHERE 
Re_table.StartDate>= '2016-08-01 00:00:00' and
Re_table.EndDate<='2016-08-31 23:59:59'   and
Re_table.Region= 'UK'
and Veh_table.No= '431'
AND Furit <> ''
Group By Veh_table.Name, Veh_table.RegNo, VV_table.Furit,Veh_table.Amount,Veh_table.Value) S
GROUP BY
s.No,s.Name
```

this show result like this

```
Name    No  Mango   Apple   total   Amount      Value
John    431   9       2       11       964      98
```

When I remove Fruit from above and try this

```
Select S.Name,S.No
SUM(total) total, 
Sum(convert(int,Am)) Amount, MAX(S.Value) Value
 from (
Select
 Veh_table.Name, Veh_table.No,count(VV_table.Furit) as total,  Veh_table.Amount as Am, Veh_table.Value
from VV_table 
inner join Veh_table on VV_table.MID=Veh_table.ID
inner join Re_table on Veh_table.RID=Re_table.RID
WHERE 
Re_table.StartDate>= '2016-08-01 00:00:00' and
Re_table.EndDate<='2016-08-31 23:59:59'   and
Re_table.Region= 'UK'
and Veh_table.No= '431'
AND Furit <> ''
Group By Veh_table.Name, Veh_table.RegNo, Veh_table.Amount,Veh_table.Value) S
GROUP BY
s.No,s.Name

Name    RegNo   total  Amount   Value
John    431       11      243   98
```

Now I want also Mango and Apple in data also correct amount is 243 . when I remove VV_table.Furit from select then amount 243 is display which is correct whereas when I add VV_table.Furit then amount 964 is display which is wrong 
I want result like this

```
Name    No  Mango   Apple   total   Amount  Value
John    431     9   2        11     243      98
```

Comment: You should not include Veh_table.Amount in the GROUP BY but rather sum it

Comment: Your first query Group by contains  VV_table.Furit, whereas the second doen't. Thus you are getting different sum values. The aggregation operation is not the same.

Comment: @StanislavL when i remove amount from group then this show multiple result and error occur Column ' Veh_table.Amount' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @istovatis yes so how i get last result? i want also VV_table.furit data

Comment: Use e.g. MAX(Veh_table.Amount) or SUM(Veh_table.Amount)

Comment: when i try this SUM(AM) Amount,, on select before from clause then this show error  Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator .... i dont want to use max.. i want sum because there is 2 to 3  diff values  @StanislavL

Comment: @StanislavL check update comment

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove **VV_table** from query without changing result if there are empty values in the field **Furit** in this table (VV_table.Furit=''). The condition

```
AND Furit <> ''
```

corrects result without that empty values.

Also, you should use the approach with with-syntax, like this:

```
WITH pre AS (
    SELECT
      Veh_table.Name, Veh_table.No, VV_table.Furit, count(VV_table.Furit) AS total,  Veh_table. Amount AS Am, Veh_table.Value
    FROM VV_table
      INNER JOIN Veh_table on VV_table.MID=Veh_table.ID
      INNER JOIN Re_table on Veh_table.RID=Re_table.RID
    WHERE
      Re_table.StartDate>= '2016-08-01 00:00:00' AND
      Re_table.EndDate<='2016-08-31 23:59:59' AND
      Re_table.Region= 'UK'
      AND Veh_table.No= '431'
      AND Furit <> ''
    GROUP BY Veh_table.Name, Veh_table.RegNo, VV_table.Furit,Veh_table.Amount,Veh_table.Value
)
SELECT pre.Name,pre.No,
  SUM(CASE WHEN pre.Furit =’Mango’ THEN total ELSE 0 AND) AS Mango,
  SUM(CASE WHEN pre.Furit =’Apple’ THEN total ELSE 0 AND) AS Apple,
  SUM(total) AS total,
  Sum(convert(int,Am)) AS Amount,
  MAX(pre.Value) AS Value
FROM pre 
GROUP BY pre.No,pre.Name;
```

It is not answer on yor query but improve the reading query and allow you to get rid of subquery.